# How to obtain JMSServerControl object

Tags: jms, wildfly, hornetq

I'm using an out of the box Wildfly 9 application server started with the
standalone-full configuration.

I want to create persistent topics at runtime, so the internet told me I need
an instance of JMSServerControl.

But I don't know how to get one.

I read: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/166207
, but that didn't really help me.

The [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html_single/#d0e6509) says I can find the resource at `jms.server`
but when I use:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "jms.server")
private JMSServerControl control;
```

it isn't found.

I'm new to Wildfly, HornetQ and Dependency Injection so I'm a bit at a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an explicit JNDI lookup. Something along the lines of

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
JMSServerControl control = (JMSServerControl)context.lookup("jms.server");
```